# Box2D Contact Listener per Body?

Tags: java, box2d, collision

I'm hoping that I can be clear on what I'm wanting to accomplish with Box2D for my game. I have the main entity (`MotherCellEntity`) that the other entities `VirusEntity`s) will collide into. What I want is when a `VirusEntity` comes into contact with the `MotherCellEntity` is for it to set my boolean `movementAllowed` to `false`, and from there, not move again, and with `Box2D` I don't know how I'd accomplish this.

I tried using the `ContactListener` but I can only set one via the `World` object, which limits me. I'm already using a `Filter` to prevent a `VirusEntity` to collide with another instance of that class.

Some Code:

```
// Only one instance of ContactListener is allowed for the world.
world.setContactListener(new ContactAdapter() { // ContactAdapter is a personal class.
    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        Body bodyA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
        Body bodyB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
        if (bodyA == mother.getBody() || bodyB == mother.getBody()) movementAllowed = false;
    }
});
```

There is probably something out there to tell me, but I can't think of the search terms. If you could provide me with the way to do this, or link me to another resource, I will be grateful.

----**Edit**----

What would be great is basically a method to check for any `Contact`s.

```
// One of these examples exist somewhere?
<instanceof Body>.getContactList();
<instanceof Fixture>.getContactList();
```

Comment: How is it limiting to have only one contact listener, and what would be the point of having more than one? At first glance it seems the code you have shown would do what you want... what is the result you get from that?

Comment: The problem is when I have 2+ instances of the `VirusEntity`, only the newest `VirusEntity` will have its variable `movementAllowed` set to false, the rest just follow collision like normal.

Comment: Then you need to add some more checks inside the contact listener to handle both instances.

Comment: I figured out a different way to check for it. Thank you all for the help.